# Can I set a variable in script equal to a value of button, than i change the variable to change this button's name

Tags: javascript

The only thing i want to do is I click a button, than the text within button change, actually i done this:

```
<button id='todo-button' onclick='changeToDone()'>To Do</button>
  <script>
  function changeToDone() {
      let toDone = document.getElementById('todo-button');
      toDone.innerText = 'Done';
  }
```

my question is I want to change the function like this:

```
function changeToDone() {
     let toDone = document.getElementById('todo-button');
     let text = toDone.innerText;
     text = 'Done';
```

but it does not work.
I just start to study js, so I want to know Is there a way achieve my second code and how.

Comment: What particular problem you try to solve? Sounds like a XY Problem. (Why do you want to do that through a variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. In

```
let text = toDone.innerText;
```

Right when you reference `.innerText`, the element's value getter is invoked, and the value is returned. After that, reassigning the `text` variable to some other string won't do anything.

In order to change the text of an element like this, you need

(1) to invoke the `.innerText` setter

(2) with a `this` of the element whose text you want to change

So, in doing

```
toDone.innerText = 'Done';
```

all of those parts - the `toDone` (the `this`), the `.innerText` (the name of the property), and the `=` on its right side (so that the setter on that property gets invoked) - are essential parts of invoking the setter to change the text.

That said, it's possible to abstract it behind a function, or to save references to all of those necessary components behind a single identifier, eg.

```
const setText = text => toDone.innerText = text;

setText('Done');
```

But that's about as much as you can do, within reason.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. To see why you can reason about the value of `text`.

```js
function changeToDone() {
     let toDone = document.getElementById('todo-button');
     let text = toDone.innerText;
     text = 'Done';
```

In line 3, text is set to `toDone.innerText`. `toDone.innerText` **GETS** (returns) a string value. `text` now holds this string value, not a reference to innerText. `text` is the string currently in innerText, not the innerText itself.

Now in line 4, `text` just gets assigned the value of the string `'done'`. There is no reference to innerText so nothing can change there.

To actually set the inner text you have to use the setter side of `toDone.innerText`. Thus `toDone.innerText = 'Done';` is imperative.